# Read users of 'Room' type from AAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, odata, microsoft-graph-sdks

What is the graph query to read users from AAD that are rooms and match a particular room type for example Conference Rooms, Reserved Space?

For example:

> [https://graph.tenant.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$search="displayName:room"&$filter=endsWith(mail,'tenant.com')&$orderBy=displayName&$select=id,displayName,mail](https://graph.tenant.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$search=%22displayName:room%22&$filter=endsWith(mail,%27tenant.com%27)&$orderBy=displayName&$select=id,displayName,mail)

On trying the above query, I see UnsupportedQuery error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the **ConsistencyLevel** header to `eventual` .

Then your query

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$search="displayName:room"&$filter=endsWith(mail,'tenant.com')&$orderBy=displayName&$select=id,displayName,mail
```

should work

Resources:

[Advanced queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http)